# Meaning of $\nabla u \cdot \nabla v$, $u, v$ are vector-valued functions in PDE.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation

I am not familiar with notations in PDE. I encountered the notation
$$\nabla u \cdot \nabla v$$
where $u=[u_1, u_2]$ and $v=[v_1, v_2]$ are vector-valued functions, i.e., for example
\begin{align}
u: \mathbb R^n & \rightarrow \mathbb R^2\\
x & \longmapsto u(x)=[u_1(x), u_2(x)]
\end{align}
Could any one explain how to compute $\nabla u \cdot \nabla v$? Thank you!

**I think.** If $u, v$ are single-valued function. $\nabla u$ is vector and $\nabla u \cdot \nabla v$ means the inner product of two vector. For vector-valued functions, I don't know. I think that $\nabla u$ is the Jacobian matrix (but I am not sure), thus $\nabla u \cdot \nabla v$ is the product of two matrix? Am I right? In such case, what is the size of Jacobian matrix $2\times n$ or $n\times 2$?

Comment: Out of context, I don't think this is unambiguous. There's the componentwise product, there's matrix multiplication, there's the dot product of corresponding columns. Lots of things it could be, depending on what makes sense in the surrounding context. Slightly fewer of them when the domain and codomain consist of vectors of different shapes.

Comment: @lan, yes thank you so much!